# FCM Pricing and Usage limits for Commercial App

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there any FCM usage rate list for commercial apps created for revenue?
Or is FCM completely free for commercial apps too?

Is there any page on Firebase documentation which tells all the usage limits and their prices if the limits are crossed?

Limits we are looking to know are:

- No. of devices can be added to device group
- No. of messages can be sent per day
- Max No. of topics can be created

Any other limits except 4 KB message size, max collapsible key.
Thanks.

Answer (score 26):

Firebase Cloud Messaging is completely **free**. The only limitations you'll encounter is pretty much related to the [Lifetime of the Message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#lifetime) and as you already know, the message size limit (4KB for `data` and 2KB for `notification` payload).

There is the [Official Firebase Pricings Page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing/) where you can see the **Cloud Messaging** is included free for all their plans (Free and Premium) services, an *estimated costs calculator*, and the FAQs. But most of the limits are for the Database, Storage, etc.

---

- [No. of Devices that can be added to a Device Group is 20](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/device-group).
- No. of messages that can be sent per day is unlimited, AFAIK. *(See the lifetime of a message for the restrictions related to the message)*
- There is **[no limit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37042108/4625829)** to the number of topics that can be created.

Comment: I would like to comment that all what you say is wrong. They have hard limits. And when your app is big enough you will hit their quotas. https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/concept-options#topics_throttling

Comment: @GillisHaasnoot I gave this answer almost *two years ago*. From that time, those *limits* were not in the documentation. Fairly sure they added it just recently as well. Saying that *everything* that I said is wrong is an overstatement. All of the details here have a reference to the official documentation. The limits mentioned in the docs are (IMHO) cases that you encounter if you don't optimize the usage of FCM very well. The topic messaging limit was originally scrapped, but probably brought back since users don't optimize it's usage. But hey, if you know more, then good for you. Cheers.

Comment: The FCM is free but, firebase have daily limit in quotas on writing and reading documents per each day.