# FCM Limitation for Android Push Notification?

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, limit, firebase-cloud-messaging

We are migrating from GCM to FCM in one of our projects.
One of our clients asked us "Like GCM has 100 notification limit" Do we have any limitation for FCM.

Can we use the same sender-id and key for multiple environments like Dev/QA/UAT and also production?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where is the *100 notification limit* specified?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as usage limitation goes, FCM is pretty much the same with GCM. See my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37962982/4625829) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40084556/4625829).

When you migrate your Google Project to Firebase, it would still retain the Sender ID. Where it is used depends entirely if it's compatible to it.