# FCM Firebase daily limit (I am able to send only one in a day)

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, firebase-notifications

I am using the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com) to send notifications.

I am testing my app so my app is installed only in my phone.

**I am able to send only one notification to my app in a day**, the rest of the notifications are showing as *Completed*, but not delivered.

My selected options are => *User segment* > *app* > and my app package name.

**Is there a limit in the free plan?**

**build.gradle (PROJECT)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
    // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
    // in the individual module build.gradle files
}
}

allprojects {
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**build.gradle (MODULE)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 24
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myfirstapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 24
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:9.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.0.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}


apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp" >


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".TokenService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".FCMMessageReceiverService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>


</manifest>
```

**TOKEN SERVICE**

```
public class TokenService extends FirebaseInstanceIdService {

@Override
public void onTokenRefresh() {
    // Get updated InstanceID token.
    String refreshedToken = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().getToken();
    Log.d("notification", refreshedToken);
    sendRegistrationToServer(refreshedToken);
}   

private void sendRegistrationToServer(String token) {
}
}
```

**FCMMessageReceiverService**

```
package com.example.myfirstapp;

import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.media.RingtoneManager;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
import com.google.firebase.messaging.RemoteMessage;


public class FCMMessageReceiverService extends FirebaseMessagingService {


    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

        Log.w("fcm", "received notification");
        sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getTitle());
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0 , intent,
                PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setContentTitle(messageBody)
                .setAutoCancel(false)
                .setSound(defaultSoundUri);

        NotificationManager notificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        notificationManager.notify(1, notificationBuilder.build());
    }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FCM Limitation for Android Push Notification?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40284336/fcm-limitation-for-android-push-notification)

Comment: There should be no such limit with that kind of extreme limitation (*1 notification per day? O_O*). There isn't supposed to be any limit at all. Can you provide more details?

Comment: yeah sure, I will provide more details once I reach home.

Comment: This is 4th day and I did receive

Comment: This is **4th day and I did receive only 4 notifications** so far out of may be 30 sent, and all of which in console showed as completed, even when not received, and I receive only the first message of the fresh day.
Please help me figure out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe for testing purpose, there is an initial limit with multiple devices, and instances.  the rest is fine.

Comment: I don't agree with this. How we can test if there is very small limit.