# What is limit or cost to send free push notification to android devices using firebase

Tags: android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have to send push notification in my android application. I am planning to use firebase but it is not clear that what is the limit in the free plan.Please tell me, how many free notifications I can send from firebase console in a day and month. Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a minute to read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FCM Pricing and Usage limits for Commercial App](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084322/fcm-pricing-and-usage-limits-for-commercial-app)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the firebase pricing website: https://firebase.google.com/pricing/
the FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging) service is free and unlimited

Comment: Hello @Ali Yones is  there any limit as per day or per month ?

Comment: It doesn't seem so, and if there is, it should be clear