# Create Push notifications for Xamarin.Android without using FCM

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, signalr, android-push-notification

I'm creating a xamarin.forms application and have got most of the app completed. My only hickup is push notifications. I'm sending my notifications to the app using SignalR and a .Net Web API Server. I'm able to receive notifications while the app is running however, I can't see tutorials for push notifications while the app is asleep. I've checked out services as well. Thank you for you help in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SignalR is not a push notification and there is a difference between them.
The main difference is that in case of SignalR you have to keep an opened connection to your hub in order to receive events / signals. So if you want to receive notifications while the app is killed or in background SignalR is a wrong solution since it is technically impossible to keep your application **always running** on a mobile device. However, push notification can **awake** your application when it is killed or in background.

I would suggest to rethink your current solution instead of looking for hacks.

Comment: Hi EvZ, I was trying to avoid having the client pay separately for FCM service when executing push notifications. I've been trying to figure out how pricing would be done since the firebase pricing is kinda convoluted. Can you give some insight or link on how much it would be to use FCM for notifications?

Comment: FCM is not the only available service. Beside that this is a totally different question not related to this specific thread. I would suggest you to check existing threads on SO like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40084322/fcm-pricing-and-usage-limits-for-commercial-app

Comment: I just read through firebase pricing and found out that FCM is part of their free-tier which is the only thing I need. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction though!

Comment: Glad to help! Good luck!