# Does Firebase Cloud Messaging have an option to limit maximum no. of notifications sent per user per day?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

We use FCM to send app notifications. Basically, we want to put a cap on maximum number of notifications that an app user can get in a day. Does FCM have an option where on hitting the cap, the subsequent messages are discarded by FCM and not sent to the user?

Answer (score 0):

FCM is a free service which currently [doesn't have any limitations](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40084322/4625829) whatsoever when it comes to the count of notifications sent and received.

If you want to enforce a limit of some sort, you would have to enforce this on your implementation (probably server side), by preventing further messages when a specific range is hit.

In general, push notification features are good for letting users know of specific (non-critical) information. I don't get why anyone would limit something when it's already free of use -- unless there's some different cost you're limiting which is directly affected by the push notif service.